# Thymeleaf: check if a variable is defined

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

How can I check if a variable **is defined** in **Thymeleaf**?

Something like this in Javascript:

```
if (typeof variable !== 'undefined') { }
```

or this in PHP:

```
if (isset($var)) { }
```

Is there an equivalent in Thymeleaf?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Yes, you can easily check if a given property exists for your document using the following code. Note that you're creating a `div` tag if the condition is met:

```
<div th:if="${variable != null}" th:text="Yes, variable exists!">
   I wonder, if variable exists...
</div>
```

If you want using `variable`'s field it's worth checking if this field exists as well

```
<div th:if="${variable != null && variable.name != null}" th:text="${variable.name}">
   I wonder, if variable.name exists...
</div>
```

Or even shorter, without using if statement

```
<div th:text="${variable?.name}">
   I wonder, if variable.name exists...
</div>`
```

But using this statement you will end creating `div` tag whether `variable` or `variable.name` exist

You can learn more about conditionals in thymeleaf [here](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#simple-conditionals-if-and-unless)

Comment: the shorter example was perfect !

Answer (score 16):

Short form:

```html
<div th:if="${currentUser}">
    <h3>Name:</h3><h3 th:text="${currentUser.id}"></h3>
    <h3>Name:</h3><h3 th:text="${currentUser.username}"></h3>
</div>
```

Comment: For objects, it is fine to use the `if` like that. If the `variable` is an `integer` with value `0`, thymeleaf treats it as a `null` and doesn't enter de `if` code.

Answer (score 11):

In order to tell whether the context contains a given variable, you can ask the context variable map directly. This lets one determine whether the variable is specified at all, as opposed to the only the cases where it's defined but with a value of null.

### Thymeleaf 2

Use the [`#vars`](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#base-objects) object's [`containsKey`](http://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/2.1.5.RELEASE/org/thymeleaf/context/VariablesMap.html) method:

```
<div th:if="${#vars.containsKey('myVariable')}" th:text="Yes, $myVariable exists!"></div>
```

### Thymeleaf 3

Use the [`#ctx`](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#base-objects) object's [`containsVariable`](http://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/3.0.8.RELEASE/org/thymeleaf/context/IContext.html#containsVariable-java.lang.String-) method:

```
<div th:if="${#ctx.containsVariable('myVariable')}" th:text="Yes, $myVariable exists!"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional operators. This will write variable if exists or empty string:

```
<p th:text="${variable}?:''"></p>
```