# thymeleaf disable message argument

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Is it possible to disable the arg {0} output when it is not available?
Example:

```
messageSource.getMessage("my.message.property", new Object[]{12}, "fallback", LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());
```

this displays:

```
Child 12 Years old
```

now sometimes I don't have the age of the children, so my args would be:

```
messageSource.getMessage("my.message.property", null, "fallback", LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());
```

the display is now:

```
Child {0} Years old
```

Is it possible to disable the {0} on the output?

Comment: You want your UI to show "Child Years old"? Wouldn't it be better to wrap an if/else around it and show "Child age unknown", or something similar?

Comment: No, the real output is "Child 12". this above is an example.

Comment: I would use two different message codes: "message.child-without-age=Child" and "message.child-with-age=Child: {0} years old". 
Trying to use a single "my.message.property" for both limits your flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution:

```
message.replaceAll("\\s*\\{\\d+\\}\\s*", ""));
```

Another solution is to define multiple message properties. One with the Argument and another one without the argument

Answer (score 0):

I hope your looking for avoid the null/undefined filed hiding. we can use the if condition in UI if the argument is not available/null, please check this link for your reference.

[Thymeleaf: check if a variable is defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28783385/thymeleaf-check-if-a-variable-is-defined/28785039)

Comment: No this is not what I am looking for. But I found a solution (I posted it)